# How to directly upload an azure VM disk to a blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, disk, azure-vm

I would like to export an **azure vm disk** directly to an **azure blob storage**? I have checked on the internet but i couldn't find a way.

I can download the disk to my local PC and then upload to blob storage. But it takes long time and manual work. So i am checking a more direct way. Maybe with **Azure Storage Explorer**?  The disk and blob storage are in the same region.

Because there is a SAS download link of vm disk, i can paraphrase my question as:

> Is there a way to transfer a file directly to blob storage by using a
> url?

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have found this in order to transfer a file directly to blob: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/06/14/how-to-copy-an-object-from-amazon-s3-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-copy-blob/ .  But it is very old post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the Azure disk's SAS download link, we can use Azure CLI command [`az storage blob copy start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start) or command-line utility [`AzCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) to upload the disk as vhs file to Azure blob storage.

For example

```
az login

#Provide the name of your resource group where managed disk is created
resourceGroupName=myResourceGroupName

#Provide the managed disk name 
diskName=myDiskName

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
sasExpiryDuration=3600

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the underlying VHD file of the managed disk. 
storageAccountName=mystorageaccountname

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded VHD will be stored
storageContainerName=mystoragecontainername

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy the VHD 
storageAccountKey=mystorageaccountkey

#Provide the name of the destination VHD file to which the VHD of the managed disk will be copied.
destinationVHDFileName=myvhdfilename.vhd

#Generate the SAS for the managed disk 
sas=$(az disk grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $diskName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

#Copy the VHD of the managed disk to the storage account
az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas

# check copy status
az storage blob show -n $destinationVHDFileName -c $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey
```